# Singleton class in python from two separate python invocation

Tags: python, singleton

I have a singleton class A.

```
class A:
__metaclass__=Singleton;
#other stuff
```

Then I have an object as follows in test.py:

```
a = A()
```

If I do something as follows from two different command line:

```
python test.py #first command line
python test.py #second command line
```

Will I have the same instance a? If not can someone explain why?

Comment: No, they are different processes.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks! Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Whenever a new process is terminated, all objects in memory will be cleared by Garbage collector. So, when you invoke it again, a new instance will be created.

Comment: They're not the same instance for the same reason that if I ran your code on my machine, they would not be the same instance.